# MultivalidatableBehavior with cakephp 2.3.0. Not Working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

I am using '[MultivalidatableBehavior](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dardosordi/2008/07/29/multivalidatablebehavior-using-many-validation-rulesets-per-model)' in cakephp. Though it worked fine with previous version. But its not working with Cakephp 2.4.0 version. Is their any changes with this behaviour. Because When I use this code.

var $validationSets = array( 'ruleset mentioned in it. ');

Though my request go through the Behaviour class but its not putting validation on the desired field. I have also checked `$this->request->data` Its also valid and for same Model where ruleset has been written.

I tried to debug using `die` in my MultivalidatableBehavior class. Though during valiation my request falls in the function of `setValidation(&$model, $rules = array()) {`. Please suggest if it is compatible with greater version of cakephp2.3.

My tried code..

Model Code :

```
 var $actsAs = array('Multivalidatable');
 var $validationSets = array(
        'login' => array(
            'username' => array('required' => array('rule' => array('notEmpty'), 'message' => 'Username is required !!')),
            'password' => array('required' => array('rule' => array('notEmpty'), 'message' => 'Password is required !!')),
        ),
    );
```

Controller Call.

```
 $this->User->setValidation('login'); Fields are also with same name.
```

Its not validating If I put `if($this->User->setValidation('login'))` it returns false.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: You say "its not working", which is a very bad issue report: What exactly is not working? Describe what you've tried and what was expected as an result of the attempt. Show any error message. The very basics of a proper issue report. That it doesn't validate doesn't have to mean it's the behavior. Add an unit test to verify or falsify that for example.

Comment: Dear Sir, I haven't got any sort of error message. I have written what sort of code I have tried in my model and controller class as well. I was expecting same if it send me some sort of error or exception if it doesn't work. `if($this->User->setValidation('login'))` returns false means it doesn't work. That is their is some issue in my class as condition returns false.

Comment: The call to $this->User->setValidation('login') is supposed to return false. Why do you expect to have anything else?
Please show the method used in your Controller.

Comment: Thats what I am saying if it return false. It should add error message to the desired invalid fields but it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **Piotr Beschel** for helping me out. I shouldn't use any sort of behaviour. It can also be achieved without behaviour. My Model code would be

```
public $validationAdmin = array(
        'adminLogin' => array(
            'username' => array('required' => array('rule' => array('notEmpty'), 'message' => 'Please enter your username !!')),
            'password' => array('required' => array('rule' => array('notEmpty'), 'message' => 'Please enter your password !!')),
        ),
        'adminForgotPassword' => array(
            'email' => array('required' => array('rule' => array('notEmpty'), 'message' => 'Please enter your email address !!'),
                'email' => array('rule' => array('email'), 'message' => 'Please enter valid mail address')),
        ),
    );
```

That is simply creating variable named **$valdiationAdmin** I have named it as admin to know following rule set is for admin.

My sample controller code would be.

```
$this->Admin->validate = $this->Admin->validationAdmin['adminLogin'];
```

Just this way. If form has data to save it would move like butter. In case data is just validating I have to force form to validate it(In case login where data is not saved).

```
if ($this->Admin->validates()) { 
} else {
      $errors = $this->Admin->validationErrors;
      $this->set('validationErrors', $errors);
}
```

It would validate my form. Even add error message to form field in ctp file. I need **not** to write *$this->form->error('fieldname');*

Thanks again to all the viewer. Suggest me something if more better. I am thinking to validate data of other form if associated with one form, with same implementation. Help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
$this->User->setValidation('login')
```

only chooses which validation Set will be used.

Use:

```
if ($this->User->validates()) {
    ...
```

to get the result of the validation.

Comment: But previous when I use `$this->User->setValidation('login')` It automatically validate my form. What I need to do in future, Do I need to choose validation first then validate it with `$result = $this->User->validates();` ??

Comment: Yes. Looking at the examples of the MultivalidatableBehaviour, the return of the call to setValidation() is not kept nor it is checked.
The method itself does not return a value anyway.